# Wpf MVVM opening 2 or more views to compare

Tags: wpf, mvvm, data-binding, view

I have a `ListView` and I want to compare different views to each other. But when I select another `object` in the `ListView` it overrides the previous selected `object`.

See this image:

[image: preview]

I'm using `MVVM` with `DataBinding` so it has something to do with that I guess, now how can you 'fix' this. Because I have no idea at the moment.

I hope its clear what I try to do or want?

#### XAML Part

```
 <ListView Grid.Row="3"
           ItemsSource="{Binding PersonList}"
           SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedPerson}">
```

#### ViewModel:

```
    private Person _SelectedPerson;
    public Person SelectedPerson
    {
        get
        {
            return _SelectedPerson;
        }
        set
        {
            _SelectedPerson = value;

            Messenger.Default.Send(SelectedPerson);

            PersonDetailView personDetailView = new PersonDetailView();
            personDetailView.Show();

            _SelectedPerson = null;
            RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedPerson");
        }
    }
```

Do I also need to create new instance of the `DetailViewModel`?

#### PersonDetailViewModel:

```
    public PersonDetailViewModel(IPersonDataService iPersonDataService)
    {
        _IPersonDataService = iPersonDataService;

        Messenger.Default.Register<Person>(this, (selectedPerson) =>
        {
            SelectedPerson = selectedPerson;
        });
    }

    private Person _SelectedPerson;
    public Person SelectedPerson
    {
        get
        {
            return _SelectedPerson;
        }
        set
        {
            _SelectedPerson = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedPerson");
        }
    }
```

Comment: If you downvote explain why...

Comment: Take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve We need some code you see whats wrong.

Comment: @DominicJonas thx for the feedback

Comment: What does "Messenger.Default.Send(SelectedPerson);" make? Where do you submit the data to `PersonDetailView`?

Comment: @DominicJonas its for sending the SelectedPerson object to the PersonDetailViewModel and then PersonDetailView uses the SelectedPerson properties.

Comment: Since you have not posted the `PersonDetailView` class, I would say: Create an additional constructor with a parameter `Person`. So every `Popup` get it's own `Person` object submited and can be edited.

Comment: I guess the problem is the following: You're sending the SelectedPerson with `Messenger.Default.Send(SelectedPerson)`. With this code you are sending a reference to the SelectedPerson. So at the moment you call again your Messenger the referece will be updated.

Comment: @Tomtom makes sense, but any idea how to avoid this?

Comment: How complex is your Person-`class`? If it's not too large than you can create a copy of your person-instance and pass this to the other view

Comment: @Tomtom Person class have like 8 properties I think.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you make something like this? So you always get a refernce back to your `object` in the `ListView` and bind the `Person` to your `View`.

```
public class PersonDetailViewModel
{
    public Person Person { get; }

    public PersonDetailViewModel(Person person)
    {
        Person = person;
    }
}
```

Create the `PersonDetailViewModel`.

```
PersonDetailViewModel personDetailView = new PersonDetailViewModel(value);
personDetailView.Show();
```

Or (if you subscribe to "`DoubleCLick` `event`" for example)

```
PersonDetailViewModel personDetailView = new PersonDetailViewModel(listBox.SelectedItem as Person);
personDetailView.Show();
```

I have never used the `Messenger` before.

Comment: Hmm, will try tis asap. But remember I'm using MVVM patern. So no code behind.

Comment: What I need is that with every select a new PersonDetailViewModel is created for every view.